# How are the originated contract addreses (KT1) computed?

Tags: smart-contracts, kt1, hash, origination

How are smart contract addresses (those that start with `KT1`) computed?

I would like to know whether `CHAIN_ID` is somehow used in its computation, or it is possible to have two KT1 contracts with identical addresses on different chains.

Answer (score 9):

In case someone needs precise calculations.

Say, you have an operation group hash `onvsLP3JFZia2mzZKWaFuFkWg2L5p3BDUhzh5Kr6CiDDN3rtQ1D` and an origination index `0` which is increased for every origination operation in the group including internal operations. In order to calculate originated contract hash you need to do:

1. Base58 decode (with checksum) the opg hash (34 bytes)
2. Remove 2-byte prefix  (32 bytes)
3. Convert index (int32) to bytes (4 bytes)
4. Concatenate opg hash and index bytes (36 bytes)
5. Take Blake2b hash with digest size=20 (20 bytes)
6. Prepend 3-byte prefix `\002\090\121`
7. Base58 encode (with checksum)

In the result you get `KT1UvfyLytrt71jh63YV4Yex5SmbNXpWHxtg`

When you call `run_code` RPC endpoint a dummy contract is originated. Its address is calculated the same way, but a zero opg hash (`\x00` 32 times) is used. For every `CREATE_CONTRACT` instruction the origination index is increased.

The dummy originated contract address is thus always `KT1Mjjcb6tmSsLm7Cb3DSQszePjfchPM4Uxm`

Answer (score 7):

KT1 addresses are computed from origination nonce. The origination nonce is made of operation hash (the operation that creates the origination) and its index (the index starts from 0 and it gets incremented for each origination in the  operation).

The operation hash depends on block header of the branch where it was included.The `CHAIN_ID` depends on genesis block hash.

So on chains with different `CHAIN_ID`s the block hashes will differ, because they depend on their predecessors, and so you should never get the same KT1 addresses.

Answer (score -1):

You have a good answer. If you want to learn more see these threads.

https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/91tis3/multiple_kt1_addresses

https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/9mxtkp/what_is_the_difference_between_manager_address/

[Difference between tz1 and KT1 addresses](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/44/difference-between-tz1-and-kt1-addresses)

[Difference between tz1 and KT1 addresses](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/44/difference-between-tz1-and-kt1-addresses/49)

Comment: Thank's for participating here. You should include excerpts and/or a summary from those sources as a text instead of posting links. Those external sources might change and then won't help future visitors of this question see the answer that was given on that day.