# How to convert bytes to an address

Tags: block, encoding

When reading operations from a block, implicit accounts and contracts are returned with a key `bytes` and in hexadecimal format.

```
"parameters": {
    "entrypoint": "transfer",
    "value": {
      "prim": "Pair",
      "args": [
        {
          "bytes": "0000861299624c9a3b52be10762c64bac282b1c02316"
        },
        {
          "prim": "Pair",
          "args": [
            {
              "bytes": "0139c8ade2617663981fa2b87592c9ad92714d14c200"
            },
            {
              "int": "11446"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

There are few details here:

```
  007-PsDELPH1.contract_id (22 bytes, 8-bit tag)
  **********************************************
  Implicit (tag 0)
  ================

  +---------------------------+----------+------------------------+
  | Name                      | Size     | Contents               |
  +===========================+==========+========================+
  | Tag                       | 1 byte   | unsigned 8-bit integer |
  +---------------------------+----------+------------------------+
  | Signature.Public_key_hash | 21 bytes | $public_key_hash       |
  +---------------------------+----------+------------------------+

  Originated (tag 1)
  ==================

  +---------------+----------+------------------------+
  | Name          | Size     | Contents               |
  +===============+==========+========================+
  | Tag           | 1 byte   | unsigned 8-bit integer |
  +---------------+----------+------------------------+
  | Contract_hash | 20 bytes | bytes                  |
  +---------------+----------+------------------------+
  | padding       | 1 byte   | padding                |
  +---------------+----------+------------------------+
  public_key_hash (21 bytes, 8-bit tag)
  *************************************

  public_key_hash (21 bytes, 8-bit tag)
  *************************************

  Ed25519 (tag 0)
  ===============

  +-------------------------+----------+------------------------+
  | Name                    | Size     | Contents               |
  +=========================+==========+========================+
  | Tag                     | 1 byte   | unsigned 8-bit integer |
  +-------------------------+----------+------------------------+
  | Ed25519.Public_key_hash | 20 bytes | bytes                  |
  +-------------------------+----------+------------------------+


  Secp256k1 (tag 1)
  =================

  +---------------------------+----------+------------------------+
  | Name                      | Size     | Contents               |
  +===========================+==========+========================+
  | Tag                       | 1 byte   | unsigned 8-bit integer |
  +---------------------------+----------+------------------------+
  | Secp256k1.Public_key_hash | 20 bytes | bytes                  |
  +---------------------------+----------+------------------------+


  P256 (tag 2)
  ============

  +----------------------+----------+------------------------+
  | Name                 | Size     | Contents               |
  +======================+==========+========================+
  | Tag                  | 1 byte   | unsigned 8-bit integer |
  +----------------------+----------+------------------------+
  | P256.Public_key_hash | 20 bytes | bytes                  |
  +----------------------+----------+------------------------+
```

But I am still unclear what these bytes are (b58?) and what the next steps are to convert them to KT1 or tz1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those 22 bytes are:

- 2 bytes - encoded prefix (tz1, tz2, tz3, KT1);
- 20 bytes - depending on the address type:

  - for tz-addresses it's public key hash;
  - for KT-addresses it's hash of the origination operation (see details in [@enforser's answer](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/3075/53)).

Here is a code on C#, I believe you will understand it :)

```
var bytes = Hex.Parse("0000861299624c9a3b52be10762c64bac282b1c02316");
            
var prefix = (bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[21]) switch
{
    (0, 0, _) => new byte[] { 6, 161, 159 }, // tz1
    (0, 1, _) => new byte[] { 6, 161, 161 }, // tz2
    (0, 2, _) => new byte[] { 6, 161, 164 }, // tz3
    (1, _, 0) => new byte[] { 2, 90, 121 }   // KT1
};

var pkh = bytes[0] == 0 ? bytes[2..22] : bytes[1..21];

var address = Base58.Convert(pkh, prefix); // tz1XrwX7i9Nzh8e6UmG3VnFkAeoyWdTqDf3U
```

Comment: in this example, which hash function do you run the value `861299624c9a3b52be10762c64bac282b1c02316` through to receive `XrwX7i9Nzh8e6UmG3VnFkAeoyWdTqDf3U` in return?

Comment: this is a bit misleading - according to https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/4227/7981 the bytes are not actually a hash

Comment: @0x10 nothing misleading, the bytes itself are a hash. The question you mentioned is about different thing

Comment: @0x10 answering the first question, you can't use just the part of bytes `861299624c9a3b52be10762c64bac282b1c02316`, but all the bytes`{prefix}861299624c9a3b52be10762c64bac282b1c02316`. If you read the snippet, you will see that `base58` is used for encoding.

Comment: my current understanding based on the linked answer is that the base58 decoded bit after the tz1 is not the pk hash of the address, but rather the actual bytes of the address because the process is reversible, and those raw bytes are then base58 encoded and prefixed

Comment: @0x10 yes, those 20 bytes are an address. And an address is a public key hash. It looks like this: 32/33 bytes public key -> blake2b -> 20 bytes address -> base58 -> tz-string address

Answer (score 4):

Something to note from the accepted answer is that the KT1 addresses do not have a "public key hash". The hash used there is the blake2b 20 byte digest hash of the operation group hash and the index of the origination operation within that group that created the address.

More details here: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/2270/5435.

@Groxan is right that it can be computed in the same way in this context, just the words used to describe the parts of the address are a bit misleading in this case. Only addresses which have a corresponding private and public key may have a public key hash (tz addresses for Tezos).

Would have replied to the answer directly but I don't meet the points required to comment yet :)

Comment: Reasonable note. I've corrected my answer, thanks!